# The maximum value of $\det(A)$ where $A$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix made by the elements $-1$ and $1$ only is

Tags: matrices, determinant, discrete-optimization

> The maximum value of $\det(A)$ where $A$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix made by the elements $-1$ and $1$ only is 
>  (A) 8 $\qquad$ (B) 16 $\qquad$(C) 32 $\qquad$ (D) 28

---

**My Attempt**

For a $1\times 1$ determinant it is obviously 1

For a $2\times 2$ determinant it is $ad-bc$. Substituting $1$ and $-1$ we can see that maximum value is $2$.

Can some generalization be made?

Comment: I think the value is $16$

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003433